# How to sort one column based on another column in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, sorting

so suppose I have a dataframe with column names A,B and C.
Now i want to only sort A on the basis of C and not B.
df['A']=df['A'].sort_values(df['B]) does not work.

Comment: That would be great if you show us an example.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a roundabout way could be to subset the two columns you want to sort, sort them, and then add the unsorted column back into the new dataframe. Like this:

```
df2 = df[["A","C"]] # get columns A and C
df2 = df2.sortvalues("C") # sort df2 by C
df2["B"] = df["B"] # add column B back in its unsorted form
```